# json_decode remove null,false,true from array

Tags: php, arrays, json, wordpress, codeigniter

I have a json result below.

```
$abc =  '{
    "id":"375",
    "name":"Nilesh Y",
    "email":"nilesh.yadav@test.co.in",
    "mobile":"9076330330",
    "tracking_number":null,
    "home_tagged_address_id":null,
    "office_tagged_address_id":null,
    "time":1427254525,
    "logged_in":true,
    "method":true,
    "error":null,
    "home_address":null,
    "office_address":null
 }';


$a = json_decode($abc,true,JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);

print_r($a);
```

after json_decode decode the result is .

```
Array ( [id] => 375 [name] => Nilesh Y [email] => nilesh.yadav@intelliswift.co.in [mobile] => 9076330330 [tracking_number] => [home_tagged_address_id] => [office_tagged_address_id] => [time] => 1427254525 [logged_in] => 1 [method] => 1 [error] => [home_address] => [office_address] => )
```

If u see the result it removed the error : null and home_address : null

`means [home_address] => ""` is blank 
I want to print that null value in array kindly let me know how to do that

Comment: use `var_dump` instead of `print_r`. Install the xdebug extension which will make var_dump's output even nicer. Forget `print_r`!

Comment: Actually i want to merge the two json output that what i have decoded them and trying to do array_merge but i thing because of above issue it giving me an error. want to merge $status = array("status"=>"success");

Answer (score 2):

Use var_dump instead of print_r. Install the xdebug extension which will make var_dump's output even nicer.

Do you see? ( http://3v4l.org/Y58fC ) `var_dump()` will output the following:

```
array(13) {
  'id' =>
  string(3) "375"
  'name' =>
  string(8) "Nilesh Y"
  'email' =>
  string(23) "nilesh.yadav@test.co.in"
  'mobile' =>
  string(10) "9076330330"
  'tracking_number' =>
  NULL
  'home_tagged_address_id' =>
  NULL
  'office_tagged_address_id' =>
  NULL
  'time' =>
  int(1427254525)
  'logged_in' =>
  bool(true)
  'method' =>
  bool(true)
  'error' =>
  NULL
  'home_address' =>
  NULL
  'office_address' =>
  NULL
}
```

You see, `json_decode()` is working as expected you simply couldn't see it since `print_r` will print nothing for a NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Check result as:

```
if($a['home_address']===null){
    //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have received your intended result itself.
When you do print_r, null value are not displayed.
The proof itself is that key exists while value doesn't.
you can confirm using var_dump